# How to write in jsonDecode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": {
    "name": "xxxx",
    "Id": "123",
  }
}
```

How can I decode this format of response when i recieve from api?

its getting error when i used

**

> Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.data);

**

error:  **`Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`**

Comment: It is already decoded and you are trying to decode it again.

Comment: Automatically decoded I meant

Comment: so directly should we use the response

Comment: Yes, You don't need to worry about it

Comment: but when i used controller.storeDetails.toString(), it shows empty

Comment: I'm not seeing your code so naturally I do not know what are you talking about

Comment: can you share any document regarding that

Comment: i just created a model class and assigned it to

Comment: var storeDetails = List<StoreDetailsModelClass>().obs;

Comment: Please update your original question and add more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the body not data.

```
Map resultMap = jsonDecode(request.body);
```

Access it like this

```
resultMap['success']
```